# Unable to get headers in ksqlDB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I want to fetch the kafka message data (key, value, and headers) using the query to do some operation.

`CREATE STREAM A ( k1 VARCHAR KEY,v1 VARCHAR,h1 ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value BYTES>> HEADERS) WITH (kafka_topic = 'ratings',value_format = 'delimited');`

output :

```
line 1:87: extraneous input 'HEADERS' expecting {',', ')'}
Statement: CREATE STREAM A ( k1 VARCHAR KEY,v1 VARCHAR,h1 ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value BYTES>> HEADERS) WITH (kafka_topic = 'ratings',value_format = 'delimited');
Caused by: line 1:87: extraneous input 'HEADERS' expecting {',', ')'}
```

can anyone try to resolve that error?

I'll send message though Jmeter.

[Jmeter setup to produce message to kafka topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iWdj.png)

Comment: What version of ksql are you using? Not 0.24+?https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/sql/data-definition/#headers

Comment: ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.0.1
    hostname: ksqldb-server
  container_name: ksqldb-server    I'm using the version of 7.0.1 the latest one. Same version I am using for ksqldb-cli as well.

Comment: Also, I have got that query from that link (ksql documentation). It's not working.

Comment: 7.0.1 is not the latest.  https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server/tags

Comment: You're running version 0.21... Added full answer below

Answer (score 0):

> `ksqldb-server: image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.0.1`

This is running [ksqlDB 0.21](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#ksqldb)

`HEADERS` keyword support was not added [until 0.24](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/sql/data-definition/#headers)

I suggest that you [upgrade](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server/tags).

Comment: I completed the upgrade. still getting error

Comment: Copyright 2017-2022 Confluent Inc.

CLI v7.3.0, Server v<unknown> located at http://ksqldb-server:8088

WARNING: Could not identify server version.
         Non-matching CLI and server versions may lead to unexpected errors.

Server Status: <unknown>

Having trouble? Type 'help' (case-insensitive) for a rundown of how things work!

Comment: Remote server at http://ksqldb-server:8088 does not appear to be a valid KSQL
server. Please ensure that the URL provided is for an active KSQL server.

The server responded with the following error:
Error issuing GET to KSQL server. path:/info
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
        Connection refused: ksqldb-server/172.23.0.7:8088
Caused by: Could not connect to the server. Please check the server details are
        correct and that the server is running.

Comment: That's just a generic network error. Are you sure the ksql server is running on port 8088?